# How to set Html.DataList.column by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datalist

I have a view that includes DataList as below and like to change "columns" dynamically based on browser windows' width when user resizes their browser. I already have a jquery function to measure width and flexible column value. How can I assign new number of columns to DataList?
DataList codes is as below:

```
<div class="product-grid">
   @(Html.DataList<ProductModel>(Model, columns,
        @<div class="item-box">
           @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", @item)
        </div>
   ))
</div>
```